# EBImage label matrix - remove small regions

Tags: r, matlab, image-processing

I'd like to label a binary image and remove objects smaller than a specified threshold. I've got some piece of code but it is terribly slow. There must be a more efficient solution in R to set a list of values in a matrix to 0.

```
l<-bwlabel(Image)
print("[bwareaopen]: Generating table")
RegionProps<-table(l)
idx<-which(RegionProps<AreaThreshold) #delete those
retImage<-Image
for (i in idx){
  print(paste(i,' of ', length(idx),sep=''))
  retImage[retImage==i]<-0
}
```

Any suggestions? In Matlab it would be the bwareaopen function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified my code because I found the *computeFeatures.shape()* function of EBImage. This function computes various parameters of the connected components such as *area*. By employing *which* you can get the indices of objects lower/larger than a certain threshold. These indicces can then be passed to *rmObjects()* (followed by an optional *reenumerate()*) to remove the selected indices from the label matrix.